# Unexpected Token on Type Import from a TS File to a Svelte File

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

(I'm new to coding so I apologize if I explain this poorly)
Whenever I try to import a type from my `types.ts` file into my `+page.svelte` file, I am encountered with a "Unexpected Token" error at runtime. The error message points to the first `{` in the import statement, calling *that* the unexpected token.

```
//Svelte File

<script lang="ts">
    import type { task } from "../lib/types"

    let toDo : task
```

```
//Typescript File

export type task = {
    name : string,
    done : boolean,
    desc : string
}
```

```
//tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "$lib": [
                "../src/lib"
            ],
            "$lib/*": [
                "../src/lib/*"
            ]
        },
        "rootDirs": [
            "..",
            "./types"
        ],
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error", //This one is shown as an error
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "preserveValueImports": true, //This one is also shown as an error
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "DOM",
            "DOM.Iterable"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "esnext",
        "noEmit": true,
        "target": "esnext"
    },
    "include": [
        "ambient.d.ts",
        "./types/**/$types.d.ts",
        "../vite.config.js",
        "../vite.config.ts",
        "../src/**/*.js",
        "../src/**/*.ts",
        "../src/**/*.svelte",
        "../tests/**/*.js",
        "../tests/**/*.ts",
        "../tests/**/*.svelte"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules/**",
        "./[!ambient.d.ts]**",
        "../src/service-worker.js",
        "../src/service-worker.ts",
        "../src/service-worker.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling a lot of different extensions including: Bun, Vite,and JS/TS. I've tried to rewrite the code from scratch in a few different files but I encounter the error in each one. What's weird is that the error doesn't show up right away, and sometimes it shows up as an error in my code (pre-runtime), and other times it doesn't.

Comment: If you have a `tsconfig.json` file, please add its contents to your post